# Filtering rows based on two columns and a running id

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, tidyr

I need to restrict the data based on two columns, based on first city and location name. I want to get all the rows for which the FirstPlace is 1 and the first city is London. Any suggestions on how I can do that? In this case, the example should display all rows for John as he lived in London for the first year.

```
year <- c(2008, 2009, 2010, 2009, 2010, 2011)
person <- c('John', 'John', 'John', 'Brian', 'Brian','Vickey')
location <- c('London','Paris', 'Newyork','Paris','Paris','Miami')
df <- data.frame(year, person, location)

library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(person) %>% mutate(FirstPlace = +(min(year) == year))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[order(year), if(first(location) == 'London') .SD, by = person]
```

which gives:

> ```
>    person year location
> 1:   John 2008   London
> 2:   John 2009    Paris
> 3:   John 2010  Newyork
> ```

Or with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  arrange(year) %>% 
  group_by(person) %>% 
  filter(first(location) == 'London')
```

Comment: thanks, can I pass multiple strings using dplyr solution, say London and Paris

Comment: @user3570187 to pass multiple strings you can use `%in% c('London', 'Paris')` (in both `dplyr` and `data.table`)